# How can 10th (or any other sufficiently low) percentile be equal to the mean number?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, means, percentile

For example, a 3rd percentile equal to *n* means that values of no more than 3% of observations in a group of observations are strictly less than *n* and that values of no less than 3% of observations are less than or equal to *n*.

However, if *n* is also the mean value, than the sum of all observations divided by their number has to equal *n* - and this does not appear possible since the value of any observation in the top 93% has to be more than *n*. I might be missing something very obvious, but it looks like having a certain (low) percentile function as a mean is basically impossible.

Comment: Data set: $\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\}$. All percentiles are identical to the mean.

Comment: An example with no repeated values: {-34, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.

Comment: You can say that the mean and median cannot be more than one standard deviation apart, so if you make the standard deviation large while clumping a lot of values at one end of the distribution then you have a lot of flexibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very used to thinking of nice normal distributions when it comes to statistics - in the case of a normal distribution, the median (the 50th percentile) is equal to the mean, and obviously, the 50th percentile is greater than the 3rd percentile for a normal distribution.

But all you need is a something deviating from a normal distribution to show an example of what you have described.

As an example, suppose we have a data set consisting of one $1$, ninety-eight $2$s, and one $3$. The mean is $2$, and the third percentile is $2$.

Comment: Just to make it explicit, if you add enough 2s then any sufficiently low percentile will be 2.

Answer (score 1):

The mean isn't about the *ordering*, it's about the *values*. The values don't have to be similar to the ordinal position. For example, the ten values might be

$$ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9999999999$$

While the median is 5, the mean is nowhere near that value.